# Showing a SharePoint document library inside multiple teams (Cloud Storage OR Document Library tab)

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-teams

We have a SharePoint document library which act as a repository for our documents, and each main folder inside the document library is shared with one or more Office 365 groups (hence with one or more MS Teams). now we want to show the document library inside the MS Teams. i found i can do this using the following 2 approaches:

1. Add the document library as a Cloud Storage
   [image]
2. Or add the document library using the Document Library tab.
   [image]

so i am not sure when we should use these 2 options? and which one is more suitable for our case?

Second question, will any of these options affect the document library permission? for example it will add the MS Teams members inside the SharePoint document library (i hope not)? or those 2 approaches will not touch the document library permissions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on the permissions on the library you want to include, and if you want it to look like a part of the channels Files tab or not.

For the end users, if you use the cloud storage approach, it will not be easy to see that this is in fact a completely separate library. It is only indicated by a faint link symbol on the folder itself. I would say that if you use this method, make sure that all the members of that channel can edit documents in the library you are adding.

[image]

The top folder in this screenshot has been added using the cloud storage feature. Note the faint indicator on the folder icon.

---

Note: You mention in your question that you have **folders** inside this library that you want to share with different O365 Groups. When using both of these methods (cloud storage and separate tab) you can only point to the root of a document library, not a single folder in it.

---

My recommendation would be to try out both of these methods and see what will suit the users best, or you can even use both!

Nothing will happen to the library you are linking up, and you can always remove both the tab and the cloud storage depending on which you end up using.

That also answers the second part of your question. Nothing is changed when it comes to the permissions on the Team you are adding the library to or the library itself.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Storage option is designed for other, non-SharePoint Online cloud services. Use the Document Library option.

Comment: No, it is also for SharePoint libraries. It is a great way to integrate other libraries in the standard files tab.